# Pyspark sc.binaryFiles() overwhelms the driver node

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have millions of image files saved in GCS. When I attempt to access them with `sc.binaryFiles(...)` in pyspark the driver node gets overwhelmed: all four CPU cores max out at 100% CPU usage and memory maxes out at 16 GB too. However, the worker nodes are all idle: basically 0% CPU usage and minimal memory impact.

I've been able to boil down the issue to just these lines:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

# Spark boilerplate
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

images_rdd = sc.binaryFiles('gs://my_bucket/')
images_rdd.count()
```

I start pyspark like this. I have 52 machines, with 4 cores each. I've tried the same with 52 executors, and I get the same effect, so I think the issue is related to either GCS or `binaryFiles(...)`.

```
pyspark --num-executors 104 --executor-cores 4 --py-files ~/dependencies.zip,~/model.h5
```

Eventually pyspark dies with this message:

```
: java.io.IOException: Failed to listFileInfo for 'gs://my_bucket/'
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.listFileInfo(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:1095)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.listStatus(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:999)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1804)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1849)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$4.<init>(FileSystem.java:2014)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listLocatedStatus(FileSystem.java:2013)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listLocatedStatus(FileSystem.java:1996)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocatedFileStatusFetcher$ProcessInputDirCallable.call(LocatedFileStatusFetcher.java:226)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocatedFileStatusFetcher$ProcessInputDirCallable.call(LocatedFileStatusFetcher.java:203)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:552)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:513)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.common.util.concurrent.FluentFuture$TrustedFuture.get(FluentFuture.java:82)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.LazyExecutorService$ExecutingFutureImpl$Delegated.get(LazyExecutorService.java:529)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.LazyExecutorService$ExecutingFutureImpl$Created.get(LazyExecutorService.java:420)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.common.util.concurrent.ForwardingFuture.get(ForwardingFuture.java:62)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.repackaged.gcs.com.google.cloud.hadoop.gcsio.GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.listFileInfo(GoogleCloudStorageFileSystem.java:1075)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Why is Spark making the driver the bottleneck and not distributing any of the work to its worker machines? I'm just doing a simple count, and I'm not pulling anything back to the driver. I don't understand how this could have any performance problems.

I'm using Spark version 2.4.4.

**Update**

As a test, even though this wouldn't help my code, I tried a different method that reads from GCS, and I see the same problems.

```
images_rdd = sc.wholeTextFiles('gs://my_bucket/')
```

Is it possible that Spark's integration with GCS involves sending all of the file names back to the driver node before downloading them to the workers?

Comment: Is there anything other than resource usage stats that tells you that workers aren't being used? Do you have a slave on the same machine? Is there no related error in worker logs?

Comment: @ernest_k I'm running on GCP's Dataproc service. I don't have multiple Dockerized worker containers running on the same host, if that's what you mean. I do see some scattered logs about lost nodes, for example; "Exit status: -100. Diagnostics: Container released on a *lost* node.". It's worth noting that I'm using preemptible VMs, which are 80% cheaper then regular VMs but can get shut off at any time. However, I've been using this setup for days and it's been fine. Or maybe you're referring to some other kind of YARN log that I should explicitly fetch?